# Error: Windows 10 Universal App Appxmanifest "Capability"

Tags: windows, azure, win-universal-app, appxmanifest

I'm using VS 2015 RC (14.0.22823.1 D14REL) to develop universal app, and I needed to use HTTP client PostAsync to send a message to Azure EventHub.
This gives me a permission denied for not declaring the capability.

I've tried using 'Capability Name="internetClient"' which gives me an error that the element "Capability" is unexpected.

I've tried using 'DeviceCapability Name="internetClient"' which gives me a deployment error as "internetClient" is not mapped.

What do I use?  Where do I find the list of all the capabilities valid for Windows 10 now?

Comment: Have you tried using the VS UI to set the capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a  list of device capabilities. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/xaml/br211430.aspx

Capabilities are set like this in the app manifest.

```
<Capabilities>
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
<DeviceCapability Name="microphone"></DeviceCapability>
</Capabilities>
```